# C++11 factory using variadic template

Tags: c++11, factory, variadic-templates

I am working on a factory that can register and create classes with a different set a parameter types and numbers. I search over the internet and I managed to create this class:

```
template< typename Key, typename BaseClass >
class Factory {
    static_assert( std::has_virtual_destructor< BaseClass >::value,
        "BaseClass must have a virtual destructor" );
public:
    template< typename DerivedClass, typename ... Args >
    void register_creator( const Key& key )
    {
        static_assert( std::is_base_of< BaseClass, DerivedClass >::value,
            "DerivedClass must be a subclass of BaseClass" );
        static_assert( std::is_constructible< DerivedClass, Args... >::value,
            "DerivedClass must be constructible with Args..." );
        creators_.emplace(
            CreatorKey { key, create_function_type_index< Args... >() },
            reinterpret_cast< CreateFunc< > >( create_function_impl<
                DerivedClass, Args... > ) );
    }

    template< typename ... Args >
    std::unique_ptr< BaseClass > create(
        const Key& key,
         Args&&... args ) const
    {
        auto creator = creators_.find(
            { key, create_function_type_index< Args... >() } );
        if( creator != creators_.end() ) {
            return reinterpret_cast< CreateFunc< Args... > >( creator->second )(
                std::forward< Args>( args )... );
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    }

private:
    template< typename ... Args >
    static std::type_index create_function_type_index()
    {
        return {typeid( CreateFunc<Args...> )};
    }

    template< typename DerivedClass, typename ... Args >
    static std::unique_ptr< BaseClass > create_function_impl(
        const Args&... args )
    {
        return std::unique_ptr< BaseClass > { new DerivedClass {
            std::forward< const Args& >( args )... } };
    }

    template< typename ... Args >
    using CreateFunc = typename std::add_pointer< std::unique_ptr< BaseClass >( const Args&... ) >::type;
    using CreatorKey = std::pair< Key, std::type_index >;

    std::map< CreatorKey, CreateFunc< > > creators_;
};
```

My goal is to be able to run this kind of code:

```
class ___A___ {};
class ___B___ {};

class ___Base___ {
public:
    virtual ~___Base___() = default;
protected:
    ___Base___( ___A___ a, ___B___ b ) : a_( a ), b_( b ) {
    }
protected:
    ___A___ a_;
    ___B___ b_;
};

class ___Derived___: public ___Base___ {
public:
    ___Derived___( ___A___& a, ___B___& b ) : ___Base___( a, b ) {
    }
};

class ___Derived2___: public ___Base___ {
public:
    ___Derived2___( ___A___ a, ___B___ b ) : ___Base___( a, b ) {
    }
};

class ___Derived3___: public ___Base___ {
public:
    ___Derived3___( ___A___& a, ___B___ b ) : ___Base___( a, b ) {
    }
};

Factory< std::string, ___Base___ > factory;
factory.register_creator< ___Derived___, ___A___ &, ___B___& >( "Derived" );
factory.register_creator< ___Derived2___, ___A___, ___B___ >( "Derived2" );
factory.register_creator< ___Derived3___, ___A___ &, ___B___ >( "Derived3" );

___A___ a;
___B___ b;
auto D = factory.create( "Derived", a, b );
auto D2 = factory.create( "Derived2", a, b );
auto D3 = factory.create( "Derived3", a, b );
```

The registers works perfectly for both reference and value parameters but I cannot manage to instiate them using the creators. During my debugging, I saw that all the parameters where given by reference and never by value.

Comment: I can't catch your problem. The code compiles and all constructors called as expected. What you expect? "all the parameters where given by reference" What this means?

Comment: I edit the code: ```auto D2 = factory.create( "Derived2", a, b );
auto D3 = factory.create( "Derived3", a, b );``` The previous code was the fix I found. The issue with this line is that I want to give a and b by value but they are passed by reference. So no Derived class is instantiated.

Comment: `__A__` cannot exist in user C++ in a well formed C++ program; `__A__` is reserved for use by language implementors (compilers), as is any token containing  `__` or starting with `_` followed by a capital letter.  So "that sort of code" cannot be written in C++ as a user.  Don't mimic system and compiler header files; they are forced to use that style in order to not interfere with the horrible `#define` abuse users are permitted to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did this to ease my reading of the std::type_index.name(). This won't be the final class names.

Answer (score 0):

Using deduced types like this:

```
auto D = factory.create( "Derived", a, b );
```

in order to do a cast is something you should *never do*.  The type deduces here will be basically `&decltype(a)` (not `decltype(&a)`; a reference to the type of `a`, not the type of a pointer to `a`).

```
return reinterpret_cast< CreateFunc< Args... > >( creator->second )(
            std::forward< Args>( args )... );
```

this requires *exact type matching*.  When this matches the type, it happens *accidentally* more than anything.

To do what you want, you have a whole pile of work to do, even if you want to only support "exact matching" of types.

Given a type `T`, there are a number of ways it can be used as an argument to a function.

It can be *moved* into the argument: `T&&`.  A "sink" argument.

It can be *duplicated* into the argument: `T`.  A "value" argument.

It can be *referred to* by the argument but guaranteed not to be modified, `T const&`.  An "in" argument.

It can be *referred to* by the argument, and possibly modified, `T&`.  An "in/out" argument.

The other options are possible, but are less interesting.

At the point where you register your function, you have to work out both the type `T` and which of the 4 above cases you are dealing with.

Then, at the point where you want to call your function, you have to work out the type `T` and which of the above 4 you support.

Then you have to inject the code to glue the incoming argument to the function to call.

We can simplify this by having fewer kinds of argument than the above 4 relatively commonly used in C++ code.  For example, "value" can usually replace "sink" at the cost of one extra `std::move` construction.

If you don't want the caller to have to know *exactly* what kind of protocol the called type needs, you have to type erase the details.

Imagine an adapter:

```
template<class T>
struct arg_adapter;
```

it can be constructed from a `T&&`, `T const&` or `T&`.  When it is constructed, it records a `void*` pointer to the incoming object, and which of the 3 categores of type it was passed.

It has a `.get<U>` method, where `U` can be any of `T&&`, `T const&` or `T&`.  It checks if the `.get` is compatible; if it is, it casts the `void*` stored within to `remove_reference_t<U>*`, dereferences it, and `static_cast<U>`'s it.

If it fails, it throws an exception or calls `exit(-1)` or somesuch.

Now you store `std::function< Out(arg_adapter<std::decay_t<Args>>...) >` instead of `std::function< Out(Args...) >`.

You know, something like this:

template
    struct tag_t {};

```
template<class Dest>
using p_getter = Dest(*)(void*);
template<class T>
struct arg_vtable {
    p_getter<T&> ref = 0;
    p_getter<T const&> cref = 0;
    p_getter<T> value = 0;
    p_getter<T&&> move = 0;
};
template<class Dest, class Src>
p_getter<Dest> make_getter() {
    return [](void* ptr)->Dest{
        return (Src&&)(*static_cast<std::decay_t<Src>*>(ptr));
    };
}

template<class T>
arg_vtable<T> make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T const&> ) {
    return {
        0,
        make_getter<T const&, T const&>(),
        make_getter<T, T const&>(),
        0
    };
}
template<class T>
arg_vtable<T> make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T&> ) {
    return {
        make_getter<T&, T&>(),
        make_getter<T const&, T&>(),
        make_getter<T, T&>(),
        0
    };
}
template<class T>
arg_vtable<T> make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T&&> ) {
    return {
        0,
        make_getter<T const&, T&&>(),
        make_getter<T, T&&>(),
        make_getter<T&&, T&&>(),
    };
}
template<class T>
arg_vtable<T> make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T const&&> ) {
    return make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T const&>{} );
}
template<class T, class U>
arg_vtable<T> make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T volatile&&> ) {
    return make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T&&>{} );
}
template<class T, class U>
arg_vtable<T> make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T volatile&> ) {
    return make_arg_vtable( tag_t<T&>{} );
}
template<class T, class U>
arg_vtable<T> const* get_arg_vtable( tag_t<U> tag ) {
    static const arg_vtable<T> retval = make_arg_vtable<T>(tag);
    return &retval;
}

template<class T>
struct arg_adapter {
    arg_vtable<T> const* vtable = 0;
    void* pvoid = 0;
    template<class U>
    arg_adapter( U&& u ):
        vtable( get_arg_vtable<T>( tag_t<U&&>{} ) ),
        pvoid( (void*)std::addressof(u) )
    {}
    T get(tag_t<T>) {
        if (!vtable->value) throw std::invalid_argument("value");
        return vtable->value(pvoid);
    }
    T&& get(tag_t<T&&>) {
        if (!vtable->move) throw std::invalid_argument("move");
        return vtable->move(pvoid);
    }
    T& get(tag_t<T&>) {
        if (!vtable->ref) throw std::invalid_argument("ref");
        return vtable->ref(pvoid);
    }
    T const& get(tag_t<T const&>) {
        if (!vtable->ref) throw std::invalid_argument("cref");
        return vtable->cref(pvoid);
    }
};

template<class R, class...Args>
using adapt_function = std::function< R(arg_adapter<std::decay_t<Args>>...) >;

template<class R, class...Args, class F>
adapt_function<R, Args...> adapt_args( F&& f ) {
    return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](arg_adapter<std::decay_t<Args>>... args)->R{
        return f( args.get( tag_t<Args>{} )... );
    };
}

using func_token = std::shared_ptr<void>;

template<class R, class...Args>
R invoke_token( func_token f, Args&&... args ) {
    auto const* pf = static_cast<adapt_function<R, Args...>*>(f.get());
    return (*pf)( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}

template<class R>
struct factories {
    std::map< std::string, func_token > funcs;

    template<class...Args, class F>
    void add( std::string s, F&& f ) {
        funcs[s] = std::make_shared<adapt_function<R,Args...>>(adapt_args<R,Args...>(std::forward<F>(f)));
    }

    template<class...Args>
    R invoke( std::string s, Args&&... args ) {
        auto it = funcs.find(s);
        if (it==funcs.end()) throw std::invalid_argument("s");
        return invoke_token<R>( it->second, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd1750cd37ac1437)

It needs forwarding overloads to `arg_adapter::get` like the ones for `make_arg_vtable` I suspect.

Overall, I think this is a bad idea, because the invokers only handle cv conversion and nothing else.  Anything else causes a crash or other undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand better why this design was not working. Loosing the implicit conversion is not a good idea. According to this other post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256800/6523086), implicit conversion should not be an issue since it is perfect forwarding. However, this design cannot register the objects. Do you think there is a way to improve it by adding a registration mecanism?